# Placename abbreviations on British roads

Tags: uk, driving, road-signs

In Great Britain (and perhaps Ireland too), road directions are often written on the road.  When it points to a place, this is often abbreviated.  For example, [at this location on Google Streetview](https://www.google.ie/maps/@51.4142413,-0.9722466,3a,75y,35.57h,69.57t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s0vFyGLczOPDm2rA07grvDw!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo3.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D0vFyGLczOPDm2rA07grvDw%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D164.44432%26pitch%3Dhttps://www.google.co.uk/maps/@54.6522889,-2.7604622,3a,26y,294.78h,85.55t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sL_3F4KSCb9IwmWpO1YgSbA!2e0!7i13312!8i66560%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656), there are lanes for *L'don* (London) and *B'stoke* (Basingstoke), and [here](https://www.google.ie/maps/@51.4360941,-0.8977965,3a,75y,338.83h,89.27t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1snru38zmtc9vzgXUJFpJg7w!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) has *R'dg* (Reading) and *W'dly* (Woodley).  When my attention is already concentrated at a busy roundabout trying to read text which is most of the time obscured by traffic, I find that I'm having to divert yet a bit more attention to deciphering those abbreviations.  Preparation would help.  Is there an official list of abbreviations used on British roads?

---

Why I care?

Within 5 minutes of my first ever drive in the UK, I did three loops on [this roundabout](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@54.653853,-2.7586739,3a,75y,166.19h,83.68t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1spZNVwRlTyTFayq_LLCUtlA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) trying to get on A66W, but the first two times I found myself in the inner lane unable to get out, as [this sign](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@54.6550327,-2.7595975,3a,75y,140.94h,84.98t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sYqI91Wxk30O9LgrgoHA1tQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) tells me to *start* in the rightmost/innermost lane, but if I stay in the innermost lane then I can't safely exit as by the time I get [here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@54.6522889,-2.7604622,3a,26y,294.78h,85.55t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sL_3F4KSCb9IwmWpO1YgSbA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) the innermost lane has become A66E rather than A66W; essential lane changes within the roundabout are indicated only by writing on the road.

Comment: I doubt it, as I've seen different abbreivations for the same place on subsequent signs.

Comment: Fuller names were already on the direction signs before you reached here. These road markings are additional hints.

Comment: Such as [this](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.411702,-0.9686364,3a,75y,250.59h,89.74t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sQP_UQ0mKj2Txixlgx1NPOw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) shown also on the road. I could not find the exact spot you posted - were you too busy looking at satnav to notice the huge direction signs?

Comment: @WeatherVane I haven't used satnav in my life, but turning right (in a left-drive country) on a 4-lane roundabout I certainly do find it a challenge to keep to the correct lane after every road leaving the roundabout.  The direction signs indicate what lane to first enter when entering the roundabout, but lane changes while on the roundabout are often only indicated by writings on the road.

Comment: Within 5 minutes of my first ever drive in the UK, I did three loops on [this roundabout](https://goo.gl/maps/oQNC39ATju52) trying to get on A66W, but the first two times I found myself in the inner lane unable to get out, as [this sign](https://goo.gl/maps/83FtxeDorEv) tells me to *start* in the rightmost/innermost lane, but if I stay in the innermost lane then I can't safely exit as by the time I get [here](https://goo.gl/maps/JwySvgQvT6p) the innermost lane has become A66E rather than A66W; essential lane changes within the roundabout are indicated only by writing on the road.

Comment: By "inner" do you mean "closest to the centre of the roundabout"? The first image shows that A66 West is the left 2 lanes. The second image shows that A66 East is the right lane. Roundabouts can be confusing, but the general priniciple is (clockwise, driving on the left) to shift one lane left as you pass each exit. On entering a roundabout (UK) and you want the last exit from your direction, you approach in the right hand lane, and move to the left as you go round. This is further complicated by having **two** lanes for a major route on the roundabout.

Comment: I misunderstood some of that: to be clear, if you start in the innermost lane as signed (most near the centre) you most certainly won't exit to ***any*** direction by staying there. Please consider a roundabout to be like a spiral, as you go round you move outwards (left) as your exit approaches. The innermost lane is signed if you want to turn right.

Comment: @WeatherVane I do find multi-lane roundabouts confusing and the UK would do good follow NL example and converting them all to [turborotonde or turboplein](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/22626/3599), which are literally built as intersecting spirals.  I drive rarely but I'm better at it now than when I had my first experience.  I do find the British custom of writing on the road confusing too, but I admit there's usually also a sign above or next to the road, although not necessarily at the same time.

Comment: @gerrit In the A66 example, you should stay in the same lane as defined by the markings - If you started in the A66W lane and didn't cross any lane markings, you'd leave by the A66W - at each exit a new lane appears on the right hand side, firstly for M6N, then for A66E, and the existing lanes spiral out by one.

Comment: @gerrit Usually on a multilane roundabout the lanes themselves will spiral outwards - so following the lane you start in will lead you to exiting in the right place - which seems similar to what you suggest, although not actually physically separated.

Comment: @NickC The spiralling lanes [cross each other (at shallow angles)](https://goo.gl/maps/s2gdPZTCk762), so physically it's not possible to spiral out without crossing any lane markings.  Making a circle rather than a spiral crosses the same number of lane markings, and only takes a slightly sharper bend.  I find it difficult to take the correct spiral on a British multi-lane roundabout.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @gerrit in that last link, you keep following the same lane you are in - which takes you behind the silver car. In fact, if you follow streetview round, you'll see the silver car does as I describe - he doesn't change lane at any point, and follows his lane to the A66W exit. Maybe it's just because I'm used to it, but to me that junction is quite clearly laid out (unlike some others I know, including the Reading one in your first link, which is horrible to actually negotiate...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No there isn't.**

Or at least in the forty years since I started driving in Britain I have never heard of one. One of the reasons is that the number of letters that will fit in the road varies, so for every town there might be several abbreviations of different lengths.

The good news is that these abbreviations are almost never used on street signs, only on road lanes. This means that the worst that can happen if you get one wrong is that you end up in the wrong lane, not going the wrong way. (If you aren't able to change lanes fast enough you might end up going the wrong way briefly, but you usually realize and can go back around and be in the right lane).

These abbreviations are used to indicate a general direction. So you should be aware that 'Reading' is in the direction you want to go. You can be pretty confident that it doesn't mean another town beginning with R, even if you don't get the abbreviation exactly.

Comment: I did think: is it going to Woodley or Whitley?  The d gives it away but that requires me to think of the spelling.